# Create gradient animation with opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, gradient

I'm pretty new in html, javascript and css and I'm using somebody's code to animate the gradient. It was a background: rgb and I have changed it to background: rgba. It still works but there is no opacity in there.

How can I get the gradient to show opacity too?

The code runs different here then it does in chrome.

JS

```js
var colors = new Array(
    [62,35,255,0.5],
    [60,255,60,0.5],
    [255,35,98,0.5],
    [45,175,230,0.5],
    [255,0,255,0.5],
    [255,128,0,0.5]);

var step = 0;
//color table indices for:
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

function updateGradient()
{

    if ( $===undefined ) return;

    var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
    var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
    var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
    var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

    var istep = 1 - step;
    var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
    var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
    var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
    var a1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[3] + step * c0_1[3]);
    var color1 = "rgba("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+","+a1+")";

    var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
    var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
    var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
    var a2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[3] + step * c1_1[3]);
    var color2 = "rgba("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+","+a2+")";

    $('#colorstrip').css({
        background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
        background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});

    step += gradientSpeed;
    if ( step >= 1 )
    {
        step %= 1;
        colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
        colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];

        //pick two new target color indices
        //do not pick the same as the current one
        colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
        colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;

    }
}

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pangolin');
/*Hoofdpagina.html styles*/
#colorstrip{
    width: 100%; height: 6%;
    position: fixed;
    top: -5px;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.5);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;


}
#colorstrip:hover{
    background-color: rgba(207, 254, 255, 0.9);
}
body{
    background: url('images/Farm background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: darken;
}
nav{
    width: 80%;
}
nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 10% 0 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
nav ul li{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
/*Styles for everything in <a>*/
nav ul li a{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;

    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 33px;
    opacity: 0.75;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    font-family: 'Pangolin',cursive;

    color: #000000;

    -o-transition: .2s;
    -moz-transition: .2s;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: .2s linear;
}
/*<a> hovering makes some changes*/
 nav ul li a:hover {
     color: #279afe;
     font-size: 36px;
     text-shadow: 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/4f69f01663.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Gradient.js"></script>
    <script src="gradient.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media= "screen" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/Cocky%20af.png">
    <title>Cocky Clicker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="colorstrip"/>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Hoofdpagina.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Mainpage!</a></li>
            <li><a href="Clickers.html"><i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true"></i>Play!</a></li>
            <li><a href="Information.html"><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>About!</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html"><i class="fa fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contact us!</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rgba you generate ,the last parameter a2 and a1 is rounded to nearest digit using the Math.round function .Thus the value of a2 and a1 is always 1.Remove the rounding of a2 and a1 and try it.